# Python rewrite `read()` class method in file-like object

Tags: python, amazon-s3, io, boto3

I'm using `mmap.mmap` to share data between processes. My goal is to dump this file in S3 via `.upload_fileobj()`. Main problem is that size is `mmap.mmap` object is much bigger than real used. I see, that default stop byte is `b''`, but `mmap.mmap` maps all size with `b'\x00'` byte. I want to inherits from mmap.mmap object and rewrite `read` method to say stop when he sees not zero byte, but `b'\x00'`. Any ideas how to do it?

Example:

```
import mmap
import boto3

fileobj = mmap.mmap(-1, int(5e8))
fileobj.write(b'usefull bytes')
print(fileobj.read(1))
#b'\x00'
fileobj.seek( int(5e8))
print(fileobj.read(1))
#b''
# now I have first 13 usefull bytes and ~500 mb of unused bytes
fileobj.seek(0)

# dump to s3
with boto3.client('s3') as s3:
# full file of size ~ 500 mb will be dumped, but I want to dump only first 13 bytes
    s3.upload_fileobj(fileobj, 'mybucket', 'keyinbucket')
```

PS. Create a mmap object with less bytes is not option, I need to extract only first used n bytes to be processed by `read()` method.